# Using ASP.NET MVC action parameters in custom attribute parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

I want to do something like this

```
[MyAttribute(Message="Please upgrade to view " + name)]
public ActionResult Details(string name)
{
    ....
}
```

I know I can call `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()` from inside the attribute code itself, but is there any way to use them in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to achieve this is to use a custom action filter and inside use either `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()` or fetch the required parameter from `RouteData`. You cannot have dynamic values in an attribute declaration because attributes represent metadata that are baked into the assembly at compile time => .NET doesn't allow you this. Only static or constant parameters could be used at attribute declaration.